# Image not showing and inspect element shows size 1x1 pixels

Tags: html, css, image

I have two similar pages made of images but on one of these pages the pictures aren't loading and when im inspecting the element it shows blank white with the size 1x1. But if i click the image's link it's loading the image on a new tab with no problem..

[Working page](http://meme.netsol.co.il/publishers.html)

[Not working page](http://meme.netsol.co.il/advertisers.html)

These pages are pretty much only HTML/CSS with a very little jQuery.
I'm not using any ad blockers..

My Code-

```
<div id="content" style="text-align:center; margin-bottom:120px;">
<div id="floating-arrow"><img src="images/arrow.png" alt="meme global publishers" /></div>

    <img src="images/advertisers/1.jpg" style="width:100%; height:1024px;" />
    <img src="images/advertisers/2.jpg" style="width:100%; height:1024px;" />
    <img src="images/advertisers/3.jpg" style="width:100%; height:1024px;" />
    <img src="images/advertisers/4.jpg" style="width:100%; height:1024px;" />
    <img src="images/advertisers/5.jpg" style="width:100%; height:1024px;" />
    <img src="images/advertisers/6.jpg" style="width:100%; height:1024px;" />
    <img src="images/advertisers/7.jpg" style="width:100%; height:1024px;" />
</div>
```

Why is this happening? How can i fix this please?

Comment: 2nd link is working for me..

Answer (score 2):

This problem is caused by adblocker on Chrome here. The error:

```
Failed to load resource: net::
http://meme.netsol.co.il/images/advertisers/4.jpg Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
```

You can fix this by renaming the filename/path.

Comment: I understand the problem is with the folder's name 'Advertisers' right? Thanks for your help, it works now! :)